# Variable access in multiple classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa project with an object that holds information from a SQLite database.
By now the information is stored in memory by this object and is used in the user interface to read and write new information.
But now I came to a small problem... I decided to create a new controller class to handle the actions of an NSTableView and I want to access this same database object that was declared elsewhere.
Which is the best option to access this information? I wish to avoid loading the information more than once in memory and also avoid use pure C/C++ codes with global variables.

It is better to understand my point by looking at the code.
I accept other solutions as well, naturally.

My idea of code is currently like this:

**FirstClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DatabaseModel.h"

@interface FirstClass : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSScrollView *informationListTable;
    NSMutableArray *informationList;

}
@end
```

**FirstClass.m**

```
#import "FirstClass.h"

@implementation FirstClass

- (void)awakeFromNib{
    DatabaseModel *list = [[DatabaseModel alloc] init];
    informationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[list loadList]];
    [list release];
    [machinesListTable reloadData];
}
```

**SecondClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SecondClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *labelName;
    NSString *name;
}

- (IBAction)showName:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SecondClass.m**

```
#import "FirstClass.h"
#import "SecondClass.h"
@implementation SecondClass

- (IBAction)showName:(id)sender{
/*
Here name must get something like:

[[FirstClass.informationList objectAtIndex:3] name]

Here labelName must display name.
*/

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either create the object once then pass the object around, with each controller retaining it as needed. Or you can use a singleton instance. I would say the singleton instance is easier to read, but it depends on the application

Comment: Where can I find more info about singletons?

Comment: most programming books will describe the concept, for implementation on objective-c, i think [this is the best way](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/04/singletons-your-doing-them-wrong.html)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make `FirstClass` a singleton. Then, anywhere else in your code, you could call `[FirstClass sharedInstance]` (replace `sharedInstance` with the name you'll give to your class method) and use this object. You'll have to be careful about concurrency issues though.

Comment: Where can I find more info about singletons?